# Requests issue - No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm new to python and I'm trying to convert some MATLAB code into python.
I have a url from the NBA website in json format that I would like to parse and return as a dataframe. I have the following code so far:

```
import requests
url = 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/shotchartdetail?PlayerID=2544&TeamID=0&VsConference=&Location=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&RookieYear=&Season=2015-16&DateFrom=&ClutchTime=&GameID=&OpponentTeamID=0&DateTo=&GameSegment=&AheadBehind=&LastNGames=0&VsDivision=&LeagueID=&Position=&Outcome=&ContextMeasure=FGM&SeasonSegment=&Period=0&Month=0'
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
```

I can see that the json loads on my browser by using the url and this also works in MATLAB but I get the following error message in python:
No JSON object could be decoded

Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: Here's a hint: try `print r.status_code, r.ok, r.text` to see what data is actually being returned from the nba web site.

Comment: FYI, for me, NBA returned `400` (Bad request) twice, then a few minutes later returned `200` (OK) and some valid json. Perhaps NBA was having a hiccup of some kind.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I get the following: 400 False      In MATLAB I can read the file every single time. The only time it works in python is if I type the url in my browser and then call the python code. Weird...

Comment: I found the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137724/python-requests-client-error-bad-request-but-works-after-website-has-been-open Seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here:

[Python Requests Client Error: Bad Request, but works after website has been opened in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137724/python-requests-client-error-bad-request-but-works-after-website-has-been-open)

Adding a user-agent works:

```
u_a = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.82 Safari/537.36"
response = requests.get(url, headers={"USER-AGENT":u_a})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try getting the text element of `r` and converting to json, like this:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/shotchartdetail?PlayerID=2544&TeamID=0&VsConference=&Location=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&RookieYear=&Season=2015-16&DateFrom=&ClutchTime=&GameID=&OpponentTeamID=0&DateTo=&GameSegment=&AheadBehind=&LastNGames=0&VsDivision=&LeagueID=&Position=&Outcome=&ContextMeasure=FGM&SeasonSegment=&Period=0&Month=0'
r = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(r.text)
```

Although by copying and pasting your code it worked for me this might be a workaround.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and unfortunately I get the same results. It seems like the  r = requests.get(url)  does not return a valid text.

Comment: @GeorgeC. Both your code and mine work perfectly over here. Try printing `r.text` and seeing what you get. If you are running Windows it is likely that your Python is being firewalled and thus the request is getting nothing back.

Comment: Thanks. r.text is empty. I am using windows. I'll look into the python firewalled. Any suggestions how to resolve that issue?

Comment: I turned the windows firewall off and the AVG software but still the same results.

Comment: My honest suggestion would be to use a more developer-friendly OS such as Linux, OSX, or BSD. If that's not possible you might want to check [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communicate-through-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7)