# Django - airports

Tags: django, manage.py

when i tried to import my airport file in my django project, i get the following:

```
INFO Downloading: airports.dat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airports/management/commands/airports.py", line 50, in handle
    with open(self.download(), 'rt') as f:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airports/management/commands/airports.py", line 64, in download
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 909, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports.dat
```

why is that happening? thanks a lot

Comment: Are you able to download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports.dat from a browser on the same machine?

Comment: i can not download it unless I copy and paste to a .txt file.

Comment: can you please help me @RobHunter

Comment: You might try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35138180/1145

Answer (score 0):

This fix is a bypass:

- Download the file as airports.dat using your browser
- Modify the source code of django-airports to prevent the download, use the local file instead (original source is commented out):

```html
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.options = options

        if self.options['flush'] is True:
            self.flush_airports()
        else:
            columns = self.default_format.split(',')
            columns = dict(list(zip(columns, itertools.count())))

            with open("/home/<download_dir>/airports.dat", 'rt') as f:
            # with open(self.download(), 'rt') as f:
                self.stdout.flush()
```

Finally, there was a minor bug in the code on line 158 which also needs fixing before the command completes (cities__in instead of city__in):

```html
            try:
                c = qs.filter(cities__in=City.objects.filter(
                    location__distance_lte=(point, D(km=25))))[0]  # second attempt
            except KeyError:
                c = None  # shit happens
```

Note that processing will take a while but in the end, I did get the airport listing I was after.